# How to fix 'make: *** [modules_install] Error 1' error in compiling linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to add a system call to linux kernel 3.14.61 that print 'hello world'.
First I downloaded kernel 3.14.61 source code then followed these steps.

1- I add `316   64  hello           sys_hello` line to `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` file.

2- Then I add `asmlinkage long sys_hello(void);` line to `include/linux/syscalls.h` file.

3- I create a new file named `hello.c` in `kernel`. Address of `hello.c` file is `kernel/hello.c`, and I put in it this:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_hello(void) {
    printk("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

4- Then I add `hello.o` to `kernel/Makefile` at the end of `obj-y` like this:

```
obj-y     = fork.o exec_domain.o panic.o \
    cpu.o exit.o itimer.o time.o softirq.o resource.o \
    sysctl.o sysctl_binary.o capability.o ptrace.o timer.o user.o \
    signal.o sys.o kmod.o workqueue.o pid.o task_work.o \
    extable.o params.o posix-timers.o \
    kthread.o sys_ni.o posix-cpu-timers.o \
    hrtimer.o nsproxy.o \
    notifier.o ksysfs.o cred.o reboot.o \
    async.o range.o groups.o smpboot.o hello.o
```

5- After top 4 steps I tried to compile custom kernel. So I ran these commands, one by one:

```
‫‪make‬‬ ‫‪localmodconfig‬‬
make oldconfig
‫‪make‬‬ ‫‪–j2‬‬
‫‪sudo‬‬ ‫‪make‬‬ ‫‪modules_install‬‬
```

But when I ran the last command (`sudo make modules_install`) I saw this error:

```
The present kernel configuration has modules disabled.
Type 'make config' and enable loadable module support.
Then build a kernel with module support enabled.

make: *** [modules_install] Error 1
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your kernel config has loadable modules disabled, thus it doesn't make much sense to install them.

There is probably something wrong with your kernel config.

Comment: carefully inspect and compare your kernel config to the original one using `make menuconfig` or similar